# Using conditional Find in mongodb, getting error

Tags: mongodb

Answer model

```
{
    "likeCount": 0,
    "deleted": false,
    "_id": "616c6224bf0d9d13009e5f67",
    "question": "6158537039d6c25f258354e5",
    "description": "first answer, hello  xvdhgbcdcd  chebcjne bebcj hevhfbej ebfhebgfj3",
    "user": "60ed857c0fc08a08284827e9",
    "date": "2021-10-17T17:49:24.443Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Query used to find answer:

```
               Answer.find({
                            _id: {
                                $in: requiredAnswers
                            },
                            deleted: {
                                $cond: {if:{
                                    $strcasecmp: [
                                        "user",req.user.id
                                    ]
                                },then: true,else: false}
                            }
                        })
```

I have to find all answers whose id is given in requiredAnswers array, such that if the user has written that answer and if deleted is true, then it should come for that user, otherwise it should not come if the answer is deleted and that user has not given that answer

Error :
[image]

Comment: if you use aggregate operators, use aggregation instead of find, and add those into a match stage

Answer (score 0):

$or:[
{$and:[ {user:{$eq:req.user.id}},{deleted:{$exists:true}}]}, // show deleted ans if user has deleted it
{$and:[ {user:{$ne:req.user.id}},{deleted:false}]} // do not show deleted answer if user has not given it
]